# Failed to import docker or docker-py - No module named docker

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've installed `Docker` and `Ansible` to my AWS Ec2 Linux as follow:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install docker -v
sudo service docker start

sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum repolist
sudo yum install ansible
```

I've found following error message when I've tried to pull `docker` images to my AWS Ec2 Linux with ansible.

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import docker or docker-py - No module named docker. Try `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6)"}
```

Docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a215d7133c34aa18e3b72b4a21fd0c6136
 Built:             Fri Oct 26 23:38:19 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Ansible version is

```
ansible 2.6.8
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.6.9 (unknown, Nov  2 2017, 19:21:21) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

Here is my part of ansible playbook file

```
- name: Pull a container image
  docker_container:
    name: mynodejs
    image: registry.gitlab.com/ppshein/test:latest
    pull: yes
    state: started
    published_ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Please let me know which I'm missed to configure inside AWS Ec2 Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the Python `docker` module:

```
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo pip install docker
```

Comment: `sudo yum install python-pip` could be installed successfully. for second one, encountered `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: try:
`sudo yum remove python-pip; sudo easy_install pip; sudo pip install docker`

Comment: for `sudo yum remove python-pip`, I've found following message `Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No Match for argument: python-pip
No Packages marked for removal`. For third, same as it's.

Comment: The following worked for me on a clean install:
`sudo easy_install pip`
`sudo pip install --ignore-installed docker`

Comment: "pip install --ignore-installed docker" : this helped a lot

Comment: `pip3 install docker` to use with python3

Comment: also if you _want_ to use python2 (wouldn't recommend it at this point), the package you want is `docker-py` not `docker`
EDIT: my mistake, `docker` is also for python 2.7, but `docker-py` is for python 2.6

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me for ansible 2.9.1 and Ubuntu 20.10 was installing python3-docker:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-docker
```

Comment: `sudo apt install docker-compose` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I completely misunderstood all answers. Maybe some of you have the same problem:

The python3-docker module must be installed on the **Target machine**. I always tried to fix it on my local machine where the runbooks are started.

I fixed it by creating a new Task in my existing runbook to install the module on the target machine:

```
- name: Install python docker
  apt: name=python3-docker state=latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this `ansible_python_interpreter` on to your 'hosts' file:

Change `[servers:vars]` to `[your-group-of-server-names:vars]`

For Python >= 2.7

```
[servers:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 # For Python3 [default Ubuntu-18.04]
```

Python <= 2.7

```
[servers:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python # For Python2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

For people passing by, had the same issue with ubuntu installed via `apt` giving 2.7.15 on Ubuntu. Fixed by installing latest version with:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt install ansible
```

that gives 2.9.2 as of today.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I was getting the error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import docker or docker-py - No module named docker.

I was using the following:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Ansible 2.10.7
Python 3.8.10
pip 20.0.2 (pip3)
```

**Here's how I fixed mine**:

So first I ran the command to remove all existing copies of `docker`, `docker-py` and `docker-compose` python libraries:

```
pip3 uninstall docker docker-py docker-compose
```

And then ran the command below to install the **python docker-compose library** alongside the **python docker library**

```
pip3 install docker-compose
```

**Note**: Please **do not** add `sudo` to the command

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was resolved after installing the `python3-docker` and `docker-compose` apt packages.

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-docker docker-compose
```

**P.S.**: If you have installed `docker` and `docker-compose` packages using `pip`, remove them by executing the following commands:

```bash
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove docker -y
pip-autoremove docker-compose -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by running:

```
sudo pip uninstall -y docker docker-py docker-compose
sudo pip install --upgrade docker docker-compose
```